# Fetching only limited data from sql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am new to PHP and mysql but I wanted to fetch only limited data onto my website from sql database using php. The code is:

```
    <?php foreach($product_list as $item):

     ?>
        <div class="p-item">
        <div class="item1">
        
                <a href="<?php printf('%s?item_id=%s','productpage.php',$item['item_id']) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $item['item_image'] ?? "1mobile.jpeg" ?>" alt="1 product" width="180px" height="180px" alt="pro"></a>
                <h6 id="des-des"><?php echo $item['item_name']??'Unknown' ?></h6>
                <small>
                    <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                </small><br>

                <span class="i-price">Rs.<?php echo $item['item_price']??'0.00' ?></span><br>
                <small><s style="color:lightgray;">Rs.<?php echo $item['item_prev_price']??'0.00' ?></s></small>

            </div>
</div>
<?php 
    endforeach;
 ?>


</div>
```

sql code:

```
INSERT INTO `product` (`item_id`, `item_brand`, `item_name`, `item_price`,`item_prev_price`, `item_image`, `item_register`) VALUES
(1, 'Samsung', 'Samsung Galaxy 10', 152.00,169.00, '1mobile.jpeg','2022-06-17 20:17:01'), -- NOW()
(2, 'Redmi', 'Redmi Note 10', 122.00,169.00, '2mobile.jpeg', '2022-06-17 20:17:01'),
(3, 'OnePlus', 'One Plus 8t', 122.00,169.00, '8t-green.png', '2022-06-17 20:17:01'),
(4, 'Dart', 'Dart brand', 122.00,169.00, 'dart.png', '2022-06-17 20:17:01'),
(5, 'Phantasy', 'Phantasy', 122.00,169.00, 'lugg.jpg', '2022-06-17 20:17:01'),
(6, 'Samsung', 'Samsung Note 9', 122.00,169.00, 'note10 back.jpg', '2022-06-17 20:17:01'),
(7, 'OJ', 'Orange T-Shirt', 122.00,169.00, 'ojshirt.png', '2022-06-17 20:17:01'),
(8, 'Redmi', 'Redmi Smart Watch', 122.00,169.00, '1watch.png','2022-06-17 20:17:01'),
(9, 'Samsung', 'Samsung Smart Television', 152.00,169.00, '1tv.jpeg', '2022-06-17 20:17:01'),
(10, 'Razor', 'Razor Smart Tv', 152.00,169.00, '2tv.jpeg', '2022-06-17 20:17:01'),
(11, 'Samsung', 'Samsung Smart Television', 152.00,169.00, '3tv.jpg', '2022-06-17 20:17:01'),
(12, 'Loewe', 'Loewe Courtesy', 152.00,169.00, 'bag.png', '2022-06-17 20:17:01'),
(13, 'Samsung', 'Samsung M21', 152.00,169.00, '3mobile.jpeg', '2022-06-17 20:17:01');
```

When i run it, it brings every images from database into the website. So, how do i only bring limited images into the website.

Comment: please share your sql code. this code is only proccesing the data came from sql code

Comment: You can do it in many ways. For example, you can set a variable like $i = 0 and exit the loop when $i = 10, or you can pull a certain number of data from the database using a limit. use whichever method suits you

Comment: How would you like it to be limited exactly? To a specific number of rows? Or to data with certain attributes? Or what? The requirement is a little bit unclear. Maybe you are actually interested in a pagination solution or something?

Comment: @ADyson sorry bout that, I want the data to be fetched in a single row containing six images.

Comment: You can use LIMIT 6 in your SELECT query, to limit it to 6 results.